# Installing Orange3 in Pycharm gives error

Tags: python, orange

I am trying to use the Orange3 library with the PyCharm editor in Windows 10 and after installing the packing and running code with an import statement (import Orange) I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/James/PycharmProjects/Assignment1/Main.py", line 15, in <module>
    import Orange
  File "C:\Users\James\PycharmProjects\Assignment1\venv\lib\site-packages\Orange\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    "pip install --no-binary Orange3") from None
ImportError: Compiled libraries cannot be found.
Try reinstalling the package with:
pip install --no-binary Orange3
```

When I try the suggested command in the terminal I get : "ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")", and it is worth noting I have the most up to date version of pip.

Moreover when I go [here](https://pypi.org/project/Orange3/) to look for more general install instructions it says to install miniconda (which I did), and enter the command: `conda create python=3 –name orange3`, which for me gives:

```
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command ...
conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: orange3
```

I have spent some time searching, and not found anything too similar to my problem online, and any insights would be much appreciated. I would be happy to provide any additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash ('-') should be a double dash ('--'), see [Create](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html):

```
conda create python=3 --name orange3
```